# How do I only process files in nested folders using Apache Camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, etl

In my Apache Camel route I send folders that are in this structure:

```
Root
  SubFolder1
     File1
     File2
     ...
     FileN
  SubFolder2
     File1
     File2
     ...
     FileN
  SubFolder3
     File1
     File2
     ...
     FileN
```

How can I split or process them in such a way that I am only sending the files to the next step? I know the names of the subfolders if that helps.

I am thinking something like...

```
from("file:/directory-containing-folders-in-this-structure")
  .<<what I am asking for>>
  .to(<<something that only expects files>>)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are the folder names known in advance? I.e. do you know there are only three folders? In that cause you can use Camel Blueprint and instantiate three instances of the same route. Each instance receives the parameter for the folder name. This is like saying create three copies of a route based on a template route just with different parameters. This is off course harder to do if the number of folders vary.